# shell script to copy a file to new file. New file name should as input file name with extension

Tags: linux, shell

I have following files

AU.GIRL..BHZ_2016-08-01T07_54_45.882_2016-08-01T08_18_05.882.sac

AU.GIRL..BHZ_2016-08-01T08_02_26.314_2016-08-01T08_25_46.314.sac

AU.GIRL..BHZ_2016-08-01T10_32_05.204_2016-08-01T10_55_25.204.sac

AU.GIRL..BHZ_2016-08-02T12_43_06.165_2016-08-02T13_06_26.165.sac

I want output file name should be

AU.GIRL..BHZ_2016-08-01T07_54_45.882

AU.GIRL..BHZ_2016-08-01T08_02_26.314

AU.GIRL..BHZ_2016-08-01T10_32_05.204

AU.GIRL..BHZ_2016-08-02T12_43_06.165

Comment: Is your question "How to remove the last 28 characters from a file name"?

Comment: @choroba yes you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the last 28 characters from a file name, you can use *parameter expansion*:

```
#! /bin/bash
for file in * ; do
    new=${file::-28}
    if [[ -e "$new" ]] ; then
        echo "File already exists ($old, $new)." >&2
    else
        mv "$file" "$new"
    fi
done
```